# Maintaining an efficient list of excluded directories

Tags: vb.net, directory, duplicates, prefix, subdirectory

I am writing a program which iterates over "every" file on a computer. It excludes certain directories from its search such as the recycle bin and temporary and windows system files. There is a subroutine to search the root of each drive for files and then recursively search each sub-directory for files. There is a `SortedSet(Of String)` of excluded directories (for quick look-ups), when the search matches an excluded directory it skips it and removes it from the exclusion list to reduce the number of comparisons.

There is a subroutine which is used to add new directories to the exclusion set. The subroutine's function is to only add directories which are not sub-directories of other directories already contained in the set and to remove any directories already contained in the set if they are sub-directories of the directory to be added.

Below is my solution to the problem. The exact locations of the excluded directories cannot be known in advance, is there a more concise and/or efficient algorithm that could be used for this purpose?

```
Sub ExcludeDirectory(directoryPath As String)

    'For simple case-insensitive comparison all paths are converted to lower-case prior to comparison.
    directoryPath = directoryPath.ToLower

    'Append the final '\' to the candidate if it is missing. This avoids issues with directories not being added to the exclusion list due to sharing an already listed directories path as a prefix but not actually being a subdirectory of that listed directory.
    'For Example: C:\Program Files         Compare To: C:\Program Files\
    '             C:\Program Files (x86)               C:\Program Files (x86)\
    If Not directoryPath.EndsWith("\") Then directoryPath &= "\"

    'Do loop chosen since items in the exclusion list will be removed if they are subdirectories of the candidate directory.
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until i = ExcludedDirectories.Count

        'Multiple listed directories may be subdirectories of candidate but the reverse is not the case so evaluating the first case is done first.
        If ExcludedDirectories(i).StartsWith(directoryPath) Then

            'If any listed directory is a subdirectory of the candidate then remove it. Do not increment 'i' because the next directory will be located at the same index.
            ExcludedDirectories.Remove(ExcludedDirectories(i))

        ElseIf directoryPath.StartsWith(ExcludedDirectories(i)) Then

            'If the candidate is a subdirectory of any listed directory then it will not be added and does not need comparison to any other directories.
            Exit Sub

        Else

            i += 1

        End If

    Loop

    'Add candidate directory.
    ExcludedDirectories.Add(directoryPath)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider breaking up your question (not your code) in paragraphs so it'll be easier to read.

Comment: Does your code error?

Comment: No errors that I have noted, I am trying to determine whether there is a better solution for this particular use.